# How would a nomadic tribe use giant creatures in a grassland environment?

Tags: magic, creature-design

Say there is an enormous grassland in the center of a continent, the prey animals could grow to huge proportions due to the amount of food and water and extreme growth levels of the food.

How would nomadic inhabitants use such animals? Assuming there are also enormous apex predators to contend against.

Comment: Eat their flesh, use their skins to make leather or vellum, use their fur to make clothes, use their hair to make felt or textiles, use their bones to make glue, use their sinews for composite bows, use their fat to make lubricants and candles, domesticate the predators and use them for hunting or war (and for the preceding purposes), domesticate the grass eaters and use them as draft and dairy animals (and for the preceding purposes, i.e., eat their flesh etc.)... By the way, grassland is a poor quality producer of biomass; grassland and "extreme growth levels of food" don't mix.

Comment: THere's going to have to be more info than this. How giant are we talking?

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations on the uses of different materials, i had envisioned them trading for people in the mountains for precious gems and metals for animal based products and these would help, i also thought about using the largest as almost mobile homes much like the basket on the back of a elephant but on a larger scale.

Comment: the size of the creatures ranging from elephant to about the size of Brachiosaurs or even Titanosaurs possibly larger.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please be more precise about conditions you ask. What are "huge proportions"? Are they restricted by square cube law? Why nomadic if food is abundant? You tagged with magic, do what has magic to do with it? And do on.

Comment: I think that the square cube law would be less important (slightly) do too magical increasing of strength, the people are nomadic because the food that is abundant is mostly a very nutrient rich grass that grows very high and that creatures could casually destroy what they would build and feel safer on large herbivores.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide the insight asked for in comments.  Reading through the comments to find the answers is actually quite a bit of work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the size (if we're talking ***gigantic**) one use that comes to mind is housing. Small groups of people could use the animals as means of shelter (by housing on top of them, with wooden constructs etc) as well as transportation.

A far more obvious answer is for **military** use. It wasn't rare for an army in Ancient Times to use elephants (when available, of course) in battle, see *Hannibal*. Elephants, especially used against foes who where not used to them and given your favorable terrain (grass plains), would pose a very serious threat to the enemy.